# Is there any way to make assumptions that apply to all code?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am trying to solve 8 coupled algebraic equations. I have simplified coefficients of unknowns by using `Assumptions -> tp > 0 && tp < 2 Pi`. Answers to the equations are very complicated. I can not simplify them because it takes a lot of time (After waiting for 17 hours, the code for simplifying solutions has not finished.)

In the solutions, there are lots of terms which can be written in a more simplified manner, but Mathematica's output (solutions) are not automatically simplified. There are lots of terms such as:

```
(-(((3 a - 2 H) Cos[tp]^2)/(6 a eta π)) - ((3 a - 2 H) Sin[tp]^2)/(6 a eta π))
```

What should I do? Can I use `assumption tp > 0 && tp < 2 Pi` to avoid this problem?

Comment: I am asking about one assumption for whole body of a code. @MariuszIwaniuk

Comment: Have you tried including that condition on $t$ as an inequality in your equations to be solved? We cannot really say much more unless you give us the equations and the code you used.

Comment: @MarcoB the code is written here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174967/how-to-avoid-complex-solutions-when-using-solve

Comment: Does it help? @MarcoB

Comment: See also [Inequalities with assumptions and constraints](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23165/245)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a global variable for this purpose:

```
$Assumptions = tp > 0 && tp < 2 Pi
```

Comment: `$Assumptions` is used only by functions that accept the option `Assumptions`. For functions like `Solve`, `NSolve`, or `Reduce` the assumptions should also be included as constraints, e.g.,
`Solve[eqns && $Assumptions, vars]//Simplify`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How should I use it when solving the equation?

Comment: It is described in the comment of @Bob Hanlon.

Comment: Shouldn't I use solution1 = solution1 /. sol[[1, 1]]; befor simplification? @BobHanlon

Comment: Since neither `solution1` nor `sol` are defined in your question or the answer, your comment makes no sense to me. If you are asking whether you should defer the use of `Simplify` that is up to you.